# Ruby on Rails App Heroku Deployment Issue

Tags: rubygems, bundler, railstutorial.org, cedar

I am having issues launching my application to Heroku. I am currently working in Ruby on Rails Tutorial chapter 1 and I'm getting the following errors:

```
 1. remote:  remote: -----> Ruby app detected remote: -----> Compiling
    Ruby/Rails remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0 remote:
    -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.9.7 remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path
    vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment remote: 
    You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing remote: 
    your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the remote:    
    updated Gemfile.lock to version control. remote:        You have
    added to the Gemfile: remote:        * pg (= 0.17.1) remote:       
    * rails_12factor (= 0.0.2) remote:        Bundler Output: You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing remote:       
    your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the remote:    
    updated Gemfile.lock to version control. remote:         remote:    
    You have added to the Gemfile: remote:        * pg (= 0.17.1)
    remote:        * rails_12factor (= 0.0.2) remote:  ! remote:  !    
    Failed to install gems via Bundler. remote:  ! remote:  remote:  !  
    Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app remote:  remote: Verifying
    deploy... remote:  remote: !       Push rejected to stark-dusk-2366.
```

I am a newbie and do not quite understand the file structure or the commands I should be using to address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run bundle install like the error said? What happened? 
Also, take a look at the [Heroku guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4) for setting up Rails, it was a huge help for me.

Comment: Found out nothing was wrong with my code. It was something on Heroku side. They have been making some updates that are causing some issues for individuals to launch their code